# External bluetooth adapter don't recognize microphone (Ubuntu)

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, headphones

i recently bought this adapter https://www.amazon.it/Plugable-Technologies-USB-BT4LE-Bluetooth-adattatore/dp/B009ZIILLI/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=bluetooth+usb+plugable&qid=1614613463&sr=8-3 (I saw thet it was compatible with linux) to use my headphones with bluetooth in Linux 18.04.

I am able to pair the headphones but without them recognizing the microphone. I tried to change from settings from A2DP to HSP/HFP but is not working. Also I tried to follow guides with blueman and ofono. Could someone please advise me? Maybe by linking me to a more complete guide?

Comment: Why could you not change from A2DP to HSP HFP?

Comment: It give me back an error

Comment: Am I supposed to guess the error?

Comment: when I select the HSP / HFP profile from the select it does not return anything. If I exit the settings I will find A2DP profile restored. I can try with Xiaomi Wireless Earphones 2 or beats studio 3